# appcelerator studio cannot find device

Tags: appcelerator

I'm using appcelerator studio version 4.6.0.201605201934

I'm using a nexus 6P, and windows 10

The phone has debugging enabled, and has MTP mode selected. File-Explorer detects the phone each time it is plugged in and tries to download photos from it.

I have put the google USB folder in the android/sdk/extras/google/usb_driver folder

I can see my device on the command prompt by going to the android/sdk folder

`adb devices -l`

HOWEVER when i go to appcelerator studio, it does not find the phone - the "run configurations" has an empty list of phones to choose from, and running it leads to it informing me that there is no device connected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to run the kill-server, and devices commands with the adb path?

In my case:

```
bash-3.2$ /Applications/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb kill-server
bash-3.2$ /Applications/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

If this still doesn't solve your problem, try to add the Vendor ID of the device to the adb_usb.ini file, usually placed:

```
Windows: C:\Users\YourUser\.android
Mac OS: ~/.android
```

You can find the Vendor ID at the hardware info on Mac OS here: /Applications/Utilities/System Information

There is also a list of Vendor IDs at the android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Your file will look, like this:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.

0x18d1
```

Comment: why is it `0x18d1`, and not `18d1` ?

Comment: Don't know, but all the IDs have that 0x. Device ID, Revision ID, Vendor ID, Product ID...

Comment: thanks - i upvoted, but this didn't work. i loved titanium studio, but appcelerator studio just doesn't work. now to see if it is a 4.6 issue...

Comment: try to run appc info, in the studio terminal and check if there is any reference of your device

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Titanium for some time and I also have the same issue regardless of what device or USB port I use. I even have the issue with simulators.

So I do the following instead:

```
# Install the application (replacing the existing one if it exists)
adb install -r build/android/bin/YOURAPP.apk

# Run the application (you could also just open the application on your phone)
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName

# Show logs
adb logcat "TiAPI:*" "*:S"
```

The adb tool can be found in windows 10 at this path

```
/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
```

The activity name can be found in the `build/android/AndroidManifest.xml` file.
It's usually: `YourAppNameActivity`

More information about logcat can be found here:

https://logmatic.io/blog/a-how-to-guide-to-debugging-with-android-logcat/

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html